# How to integrate Google credentials in an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to make my application to run using Google credentials.

I'm doing an application where user can get his list of events from the  server by giving local credentials. I want to make my application run when the user enters Google credentials.
How can integrate that to my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try on [Google Data objective C](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/) API.. Which handles all google service. i guess you can handle google credentials here..